# Using R to clean data, collapsing multiple rows into single row per event, but keeping specific information from other rows

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am working on a dataset which has multiple rows per event, and my boss has asked me to tidy it so that there is one row per event. The complexity is that there is no consistent (in a programmatic sense) way of choosing one row over another - there are three variables which might need to be taken from different rows in any given situation.

Because of this, I have gone through the data manually and have created a new variable next to each of these variables, stating which row should be kept for that variable. I now would like to be able to automate the process of collapsing the data to have one row per event and saving information from the correct row in each of the three variables.

Please see below for a dummy dataset:

| Event | Area | Keep_area | Date | Keep_dat | Outcome | Keep_out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A |  | 01/01/22 | Y | Fail |  |
| 1 | B | Y | 13/04/22 |  | Unknown |  |
| 1 | C |  | 24/07/22 |  | Success | Y |
| 2 | B | Y | 18/10/21 | Y | Unknown |  |
| 2 | G |  | 02/11/22 |  | Success | Y |
| 3 | C |  | 12/01/22 |  | Fail |  |
| 3 | E |  | 28/03/22 | Y | Unknown |  |
| 3 | F | Y | 16/12/22 |  | Unknown |  |
| 3 | G |  | 21/01/23 |  | Unknown |  |
| 3 | A |  | 02/02/23 |  | Partial | Y |

And this is how I'd want it to look:

| Event | Area | Date | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | 01/01/22 | Success |
| 2 | B | 18/10/21 | Success |
| 3 | F | 28/03/22 | Partial |

I know I will probably need to do this in multiple stages, but I'm just struggling to work out how I can use the "keep" variables to say which to keep. I would ideally like to do this in tidyverse but am open to any and all suggestions!

I can't even begin to work out what to do here (sorry, still relatively new to R!) so all I've been able to do so far is identify which pieces of information need to be kept from each row (as shown above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally evidence with your code of what you have tried is expected but I acknowledge it can be difficult knowing where to start and this is complex if you're starting out so here is a way to do it. One of the easiest ways to do this type of data wrangling is using `pivot_longer()`, then return to its' wide format using `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# df is your data
df %>% pivot_longer(!Event) %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(value == "Y", lag(value), NA)) %>%
  select(!value) %>%
  filter(!is.na(temp)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,,
              values_from = temp) %>%
  rename(Date = "Keep_dat")

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Event       Date  Keep_area  Keep_out
  <int>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   
1     1 1/01/2022      B        Success 
2     2 18/10/2021     B        Success 
3     3 28/03/2022     F        Partial
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to ensure I understand, does this essentially turn each row into a column, and then the lag() means that the value immediately prior to any "Y" is kept? And then do I replace "value" with whichever variable I am working on (i.e. do I need to do this multiple times, once for each variable)?

Comment: @mimkat - yes, it creates a single column that combines all the data in every column except "Event", so one "event" row for each column if that makes sense. You can select up to each pipe e.g. %>% and run just part of the code to see what each step does.  So run `df %>% pivot_longer(!Event)`, then `df %>% pivot_longer(!Event) %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(value == "Y", lag(value), NA))` etc. to see what it does. I also just updated the code as the date column was incorrect.

Comment: @mimkat this approach exploits the fact that the columns with the data you want are followed by the columns containing the "Y" values. So when you `pivot_longer()`, the default is that columns are stacked in the order they appear. So the values that you want will always have a "Y" directly below them. It works on every variable you're working on simultaneously.

Comment: There is a trivial solution - just filter each column and bind them! See below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/77578475/22859010)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the tagging has been done correctly, you can just filter each column and stick them together.

```
library(dplyr)
df_clean <- cbind(
  df |> filter(Keep_area=="Y") |> select(Event, Area),  
  df |> filter(Keep_dat=="Y") |> select(Date), 
  df |> filter(Keep_out=="Y") |> select(Outcome)
)

> df_clean
  Event Area     Date Outcome
1     1    B 01/01/22 Success
2     2    B 18/10/21 Success
3     3    F 28/03/22 Partial
```

To check the tagging is correct, you can run this code first to report any events where there is not exactly one "Y" per variable.

```
df |>
  group_by(Event) |>
  summarise(area_count = sum(Keep_area=="Y", na.rm = T),
            date_count = sum(Keep_dat=="Y", na.rm = T),
            outcome_count = sum(Keep_out=="Y", na.rm = T)) |>
  filter(area_count != 1 | date_count != 1 | outcome_count != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very ugly solution, but should work in your case.

For my solution to work, you first keep to `rename` your columns so that "Keep_" and it's partner has the same name.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_renamed <- df |> 
  rename("Keep_Area" = "Keep_area",
         "Keep_Date" = "Keep_dat",
         "Keep_Outcome" = "Keep_out")

colnames(df_renamed)
[1] "Event"        "Area"         "Keep_Area"    "Date"         "Keep_Date"   
[6] "Outcome"      "Keep_Outcome"
```

Then, choose a special character that you sure will not appear in your real dataset, for example I have chosen "@@" here. Concatenate that special character to your "Keep_*" column together with the values you want to keep (i.e. `Area`, `Date` and `Outcome`). After a series of pivoting and filtering operation, you only select the rows with the pattern "Y@@", which is the values you want to keep. Finally reshape a little bit to get your desired output.

```
df_renamed |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Keep"), ~paste0(.x, "@@", get(sub("Keep_", "", cur_column()))))) |> 
  pivot_longer(-Event, names_to = c("Var", ".value"), names_sep = "_") |> 
  pivot_longer(Area:Outcome) |> 
  filter(grepl("Y@@", value)) |> 
  pivot_wider() |> 
  select(-Var) |> 
  mutate(across(-Event, ~sub("Y@@", "", .x)))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Event Date     Area  Outcome
  <int> <chr>    <chr> <chr>  
1     1 01/01/22 B     Success
2     2 18/10/21 B     Success
3     3 28/03/22 F     Partial
```